# Ipad ModalView rotation problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller, device-orientation

I created a UISplitView, after the splitView is load in landscape mode, I display a modalView using the presentModalView, my problem is that the modalView is always in portrait mode, can't find the solution for that.

`UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

it gives me the landscape orientation but using

`UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`

gives me Portrait. (not working under 4.2)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using an NSTimer and loas my function with it and its work, thats a bit tricky but that is the only solution I found right now.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(loadingModal:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```